# Can every polynomial generate an ideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ideals

Suppose an arbitrary polynomial $f$ in a polynomial ring $R$. Is $\langle f\rangle$ always an ideal?

*Helper parts*

> 1. Consider a finite polynomial ring. Let $R=R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Is the answer Hilbert basis theorem? Consider $f\in R$, is $\langle f\rangle$ an ideal?
>
> > *([Hilbert Basis Theorem](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-972-algebraic-techniques-and-semidefinite-optimization-spring-2006/lecture-notes/lecture_13.pdf)). Every polynomial ideal in C[x] is finitely generated.*
>
> 2. In contrast when $R$ is an infinite polynomial ring: does [Hilbert Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz) explain things? Can every infinite polynomial generate an ideal?

Comment: where? In a ring of polynomials it does. The set of all (finite sums of) multiples of $f$ is always an ideal

Comment: @ArcadioBuendía is this explained by Hilbert Basis theorem in the finite case while by Hilbert Nullstellensatz in infinite case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. More generally, let $R$ be a ring. For any $a\in R$, the subset $\langle a\rangle$ is the *[principal ideal of $R$ generated by $a$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Principal_Ideal)*. This ideal is the smallest ideal of $R$ containing $a$.

A proof can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Principal_Ideal_is_Ideal).

In your case, $R$ is some polynomial ring $R=A[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ for a ring $A$.

Comment: Does this follow from some theorem like Hilbert Basis theorem or Hilbert Nullstellensatz?

Comment: No, the proof is quite straightforward. I've updated my answer with a link to the proof.